# Multi Filter outside Table

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, server-side

I'm using datatables as a tool in creating tables for my site. You can see it in action **[here](http://oss-dev.forexworld.us/datatables-test/)**.

Everything's working as expected but I'd like the multi filters to be outside the table. I tried making another table and place it on top - although the input boxes are shown, they don't work.

Here's my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#cq-datatables-<?php echo $datatable_id; ?> tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
    var table = $('#cq-datatables-<?php echo $datatable_id; ?>').DataTable( 
    {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/cq-datatables/datatables/scripts/post.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function(dtParms){ 
                        dtParms.table_name = "<?php echo $retrieve_table_name; ?>";
                        dtParms.column_names = '<?php echo $column_names; ?>';
                        return dtParms;
                    }
        },
        initComplete: function() {
          var api = this.api();

          // Apply the search
          api.columns().every(function() {
            var that = this;

            $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
              if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                that
                  .search(this.value)
                  .draw();
              }
            });
          });
        },
        "columns": [<?php echo $test; ?>],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ],
        "dom": '<"row"<"col-md-12"<"pull-right"B>l>><"custom-spacer"f>rtip',
        "buttons": [
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5',
            'print',
            'colvis'
        ]
    } 
    );
} );
</script>
    <table id="cq-datatables-<?php echo $datatable_id; ?>" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php
                    $table_counter = 0;
                    foreach ($cq_existing_columns as $table_columns) {
                        echo "<th>".ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $table_columns))."</th>";
                    }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        $table_counter = 0;
                        foreach ($cq_existing_columns as $table_columns) {
                            echo "<th>".ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $table_columns))."</th>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Here's the UI, but the search function is not working as expected.

[image]
Eli

Comment: I saw the example on your site. Search filter outside the table works fine.

Comment: Hi @AmiyaRanjan, currently the search filter is inside the table - on the footer. I'd like it to be outside and on top but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am doing the same thing in this way. Hope it helps you.

<input type="text" id="searchBox1" placeholder="Search Here.."></input>
<input type="text" id="searchBox2" placeholder="Search Here.."></input>
<input type="button" value="Search"  id="searchButton" name="search">

$('#searchButton').on('click', function () {
    table.draw();
});

And the data param of datatable ajax will be like this :
'data' :function (d){
      d.search_term1 = $("#searchBox1").val(),
      d.search_term2 = $("#searchBox2").val()
}
```

Comment: Hi @AmiyaRanjan, is there a way to do it the datatables way? They are dynamically generated.

So for now, I have the codes from above where I use .each() function. I just want to put them outside.

Comment: Hi @jeepers_creepers its not possible to do it on datatables way as datatable is table specific and it cann't handle events of another table. It only handles the table on which it initialized. You can draw table on search field .keyup().